# Round number in formulae computation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible in a google sheet formulae to round an intermediate number that will be used to perform other computation before yielding final result?
Here an example:

```
="Rent                               (" & E5*100/Control!D9 & "%)"
```

with `E5*100/Control!D9` what I would like to round?

Answer (score 3):

*You may try:*

```js
="Rent                               ("&round(E5*100/Control!D9,2)&"%)"
```

Comment: I do not see a need to _try_ this ?

Comment: my understanding is If *E5* has `2` & *D9* has `3`; OP do not want to see this → `Rent                               (66.6666666666667%)` & instead maybe this →  `Rent                               (66.67%)`

Comment: no need to _try_, this statement just works.... 

Answer (score -1):

Using `round` with `;` to separate arguments did the trick :)